# How to cast column of Unicode in data frame to integer?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, unicode, series

I have a pandas data frame(named comments) and one of its columns was time stamps(e.g:2018-11-26 ), I split the column into three separate columns (year, month and day) but the data are still Unicode. I am trying to put each column's data to an array and then cast them into integers.

I tried two different codes but I get an error:
"only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

here is my code:

```
    day_array=comments['day'].values
    mounth_array=comments['mounth'].values
    year_array=comments['year'].values

    #My first try:
    for i in day_array:
        day_array[i] = int(day_array[i])

    #My second try instead of first one:
    for i in day_array:
        hi=day_array[i]
        limit = int(hi)
        limit[i]=limit
```

I know when I run this: "limit = int(hi)", the limit type will be an integer but I do not know why it doesn't fit into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop for this, just use *astype*.

You can use something like:

`comments['day'] = comments['day'].astype('int32')`

You might want to refer [pandas.DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).